# MEAN Stack CORS error even after using CORS middleware

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cors, mean-stack

I am working on an Angular app with NodeJs backend and I am getting CORS error even after using CORS middleware. Have a look at my code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
let corsOptions = {
    origin: ['http://localhost:4200', 'localhost:4200'],
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
//Code
});
```

Here is the error on Chrome:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8088/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.
auth.service.ts:16

POST localhost:8088/login net::ERR_FAILED
```

How do I solve this CORS error now let me now please!

Comment: The error message you're getting likely is accurate. In your client code, you likely forgot the `http://` or `https://` part in the target URL.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided has an issue with the origin URLs specified in the corsOptions object. The origins should include the scheme (e.g., "http://") but they are missing it. To fix the CORS error, update the corsOptions object like this:

```
let corsOptions = {
    origin: ['http://localhost:4200'],
}
```

This change ensures that the CORS middleware works correctly, allowing your Angular app to communicate with the Node.js backend without encountering CORS errors.

Comment: I have made the change but still the CORS error!
const cors = require('cors');
let corsOptions = {
    origin: ['http://localhost:4200']
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));